# How to change the value of a list based on if statements Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a pygame game where the sprite list changes based on a clicks.

```
p1 = 1
p2 = 1
if p1 == 1:
  list1_1 = [EXAMPLE]
  list1_2 = [EXAMPLE] 
if p1 == 2:
  list1_1 = [EXAMPLE]
  list1_2 = [EXAMPLE]
if p2 == 1:
  list2_1 = [EXAMPLE]
  list2_2 = [EXAMPLE]
if p2 == 2:
  list2_1 = [EXAMPLE]
  list2_2 = [EXAMPLE]

def button():
  if clicked:
    if action == EXAMPLE:
      p1 = 1
    if action == EXAMPLE:
      p1 = 2 
    if action == EXAMPLE:
      p2 = 1
      game()
    if action == EXAMPLE:
      p2 = 2  
      game()  

def menu():
  button(info) 

def game():
  EXTRA

menu()
```

so that's a very shortened version of my game with what is probably my main code in fault. the problem is as I click the buttons to change the value it doesn't actually change the values of the lists; list1_1, list1_2, list2_1 and list2_2.

Comment: That is because for your button() function, p1 and p2 are changed locally, only in that function. You can use **global** keyword to change their values globally or use classes here.

Comment: you could put all that logic for changing the list values inside a method and call it when ever there was a button click.

Comment: so when would I use global in the button function? If so would I do 'global p1' before the if statements or do 'global p1 = 1'

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow @Psych, using the 'global p1 = 1'  would not actually change the values in the list.

Comment: Of what I see the lists seem to be hardcoded upon initialisation, you are never changing the lists within button(), you are only changing the variables *p1* and *p2*. Also, you might have a variable scope problem. You can read more about that in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, the list values are initialized when the program starts to run and they are not changed after, hence they do not change. I think you want to run the first 14 lines of the code which updates the list values, whenever there was a button click. There are many ways you could do this, one idea would be to put them all inside a method and then calling it to update the global values whenever you want to change them. for example,

```
# initialize the lists globally 
list1_1, list1_2, list1_2_1, list1_2_2 = [[]] * 4

pl = 1
p2 = 1

def do_some_action(p1=1, p2=1):
    if p1 == 1:
        global list1_1 = [EXAMPLE]
        global list1_2 = [EXAMPLE]
    if p1 == 2:
        global list1_1 = [EXAMPLE]
        global list1_2 = [EXAMPLE]
    if p2 == 1:
        global list2_1 = [EXAMPLE]
        global list2_2 = [EXAMPLE]
    if p2 == 2:
        global list2_1 = [EXAMPLE]
        global list2_2 = [EXAMPLE]

do_some_action(p1, p2)

def button():
    if clicked:
        if action == EXAMPLE:
            global p1 = 1
            do_some_action(p1, p2)
        if action == EXAMPLE:
            global p1 = 2
            do_some_action(p1, p2)
        if action == EXAMPLE:
            global p2 = 1
            do_some_action(p1, p2)
            game()
        if action == EXAMPLE:
            global p2 = 2
            do_some_action(p1, p2)
            game()

def menu():
    button(info)

def game():
    EXTRA

menu()
```